# v-for look using curly brackets

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I ran into a situation that I need to loop true items without producing any HTML. I expect the code to look something like this.

```
      <table id="detailTable">
        <tr>
          <th class='editRow'></th>
          <th class='editRow'></th>
          <!-- <th class='editRow'></th> -->
          <th v-for='(columns, index) in $parent.columns' :key='index'>{{ firstLetterCaps(columns) }}</th>
        </tr>
        {{ for (row, index) in $parent.results }}
        <resultsRows v-for='(row, index) in $parent.results' :key='index' :row='row' :index='index' :deleteQueryObjects='$parent.deleteQueryObjects'></resultsRows>
        <resultsCommentRow v-for='(row, index) in $parent.results' :index='index'></resultsCommentRow>
        {{ end-for}}
      </table>
```

To make it clear I expect instead of using `<div v-for=item in items></div>` to this `{ for item in items } { end for }` does this exist for vue ?

Comment: Please show the expected output HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such a syntax in `vuejs`, if you want to loop on something without touching it you can use `<template>` like :

```
<template v-for="element in elements" >
...
</template>
```

`template` tag description from : https://www.w3schools.com/TagS/tag_template.asp 
you can go deeper : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

In your case :

```
<template v-for='(row, index) in $parent.results' >
    <resultsRows :row='row' :index='index' :deleteQueryObjects = '$parent.deleteQueryObjects' />
    <resultsCommentRow :index='index' />
</template>
```